# SSRS passing IN clause to Redshift

Tags: reporting-services, amazon-redshift

I have an query similar to the following that I am trying pass to Redshift using SSRS.
Examples:

This works fine from SSRS to Redshift.
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN1 = ?

This returns only one value related what I put in the SSRS parameter. What I need is the following and I am struggling to find example where this is done with Redshift.

SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN1 IN (@parameter)

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN1 IN (?)` ? The parameter should replace the ? like it does for the EQUALS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS doesn't support milti-value parameters in `IN` clauses with **ODBC** connections. One workaround is to format the condition in your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
position(',' || column || ',' in ?) > 0
```

And pass in the parameter values in the dataset properties like this:

```
="," + Join(Parameters!Parameter.Value, ",") + ","
```

So the report is taking the array of selected values, concatenating them into a comma-separated string, and then letting the query do a string search to check for matches.